# How to add class to dynamically generated text box in DOM?

Tags: javascript

I created a textbox using Javascript.

How to assign class to textbox in Javascript?

Comment: *"Reply me fast"* that is not how it works here....

Comment: @Felix.... however... it does... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a reference to your text-box node, you can just assign a CSS class by setting the `className` property on the node, like:

```
myTextBox.className = "someClass";
```